# How to sort a list of dictionaries by two values, one of which is an IP address

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, ip

I have a list in Python that shows the network location of some machines:

```
[{"address": "54.23.65.111", "role": "logic"}, 
{"address": "51.63.68.115", "role": "logic"},    
{"address": "79.23.65.111", "role": "output"},    
{"address": "52.23.65.111", "role": "logic"}]
```

And I would like this sorted by role first and then numerically by address, so the output should look like:

```
[{"address": "51.63.68.115", "role": "logic"},    
{"address": "52.23.65.111", "role": "logic"},    
{"address": "54.23.65.111", "role": "logic"},     
{"address": "79.23.65.111", "role": "output"}]
```

So far I have:

```
for machine_dict in sorted(machine_list, key=lambda machine_role: (machine_role["role"], machine_role["address"])):
```

But this doesn't sort the IPs numerically, it reckons `11.something` is less than `2.something` for example.

Comment: *"it reckons `11.something` is less than `2.something`"* - that *is* sorting the IPs lexicographically...

Comment: I think you mean numerically sort the IPs?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I think I did mean numerically sort the IPs. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

To numerically sort the IPs you need to split the address but the general approach of @sparkandshine still works, with just a slight update to the key:

```
>>> list_dicts = [{"address": "11.23.65.111", "role": "logic"},
...               {"address": "2.63.68.115", "role": "logic"},
...               {"address": "79.23.65.111", "role": "output"},
...               {"address": "52.23.65.111", "role": "logic"}]
>>> sorted(list_dicts, key=lambda d: (d['role'], tuple(map(int, d['address'].split('.')))))
[{'address': '2.63.68.115', 'role': 'logic'},
 {'address': '11.23.65.111', 'role': 'logic'},
 {'address': '54.23.65.111', 'role': 'logic'},
 {'address': '79.23.65.111', 'role': 'output'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort by IP addresses like you want, this could work :

```
import socket
print sorted(machine_list, 
             key = lambda machine_role: (machine_role["role"],
                                         socket.inet_aton(machine_role["address"])))
```

Input

```
[
    {'role': 'logic',  'address': '1.2.3.4'}, 
    {'role': 'logic',  'address': '1.11.2.3'}, 
    {'role': 'logic',  'address': '1.1.2.3'}, 
    {'role': 'logic',  'address': '2.3.4.5'}
]
```

Output

```
[
    {'role': 'logic', 'address': '1.1.2.3'}, 
    {'role': 'logic', 'address': '1.2.3.4'}, 
    {'role': 'logic', 'address': '1.11.2.3'}, 
    {'role': 'logic', 'address': '2.3.4.5'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert ip address as a list of `int`s using `.split('.')`, i.e., `[int(i) for i in d['address'].split('.')]`

```
list_dicts = [  {"address": "11.23.65.111", "role": "logic"},
                {"address": "2.63.68.115", "role": "logic"},
                {"address": "79.23.65.111", "role": "output"},
                {"address": "52.23.65.111", "role": "logic"}]


result = sorted(list_dicts, key=lambda d: (d['role'], [int(i) for i in d['address'].split('.')]))

print(result)
# Output
[{'role': 'logic', 'address': '2.63.68.115'}, {'role': 'logic', 'address': '11.23.65.111'}, {'role': 'logic', 'address': '52.23.65.111'}, {'role': 'output', 'address': '79.23.65.111'}]
```

---

Or use the Python module [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#module-ipaddress),

```
import ipaddress

result = sorted(list_dicts, key=lambda d: (d['role'], ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(d['address']))))  # unicode for Python2
```

Comment: That's exactly what the OP is currently using...

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thx for pointing out this. I just edited my answer. Expecting your feedback.